Parsing JSON with Forge
Any idea how to fix this?
According to the Foundry Book it can parse JSON.
I get this JSON body returned from cast:
{
  "status": "0x1",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": "0x12ca628",
  "logs": [
    {
      "address": "0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c",
      "topics": [
        "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x000000000000000000000000b04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693"
      ],
      "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000",
      "blockHash": "0x758a5188cc2b9d071a0cc4b855128b3091e9187ba9997890e6a039521797aa85",
      "blockNumber": "0x6b9def",
      "transactionHash": "0x5fa27ec697ddbb055b5474857621f34476380476758b7d3407e262aed6815e1c",
      "transactionIndex": "0x37",
      "logIndex": "0x2b",
      "removed": false
    },
    {
      "address": "0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c",
      "topics": [
        "0xb9203d657e9c0ec8274c818292ab0f58b04e1970050716891770eb1bab5d655e"
      ],
      "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000000000000000000000000000b04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693",
      "blockHash": "0x758a5188cc2b9d071a0cc4b855128b3091e9187ba9997890e6a039521797aa85",
      "blockNumber": "0x6b9def",
      "transactionHash": "0x5fa27ec697ddbb055b5474857621f34476380476758b7d3407e262aed6815e1c",
      "transactionIndex": "0x37",
      "logIndex": "0x2c",
      "removed": false
    }
  ],
  "logsBloom": "",
  "type": "0x2",
  "transactionHash": "0x5fa27ec697ddbb055b5474857621f34476380476758b7d3407e262aed6815e1c",
  "transactionIndex": "0x37",
  "blockHash": "0x758a5188cc2b9d071a0cc4b855128b3091e9187ba9997890e6a039521797aa85",
  "blockNumber": "0x6b9def",
  "gasUsed": "0x9160",
  "effectiveGasPrice": "0x9b203279",
  "from": "0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693",
  "to": "0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c",
  "contractAddress": null
}

This is my contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import {HelperFctns} from "./HelperFctns.sol";
import {Router} from "../src/Router.sol";
import {Test} from "../lib/forge-std/src/Test.sol";
import {XToken} from "../src/XToken.sol";
import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {TransactionReceipt} from "./Structs.sol";

contract Functions is Test{
    HelperFctns public helperFctns;
    
    function mint(string calldata _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount) public {
        // cast send "$XToken" "mint(uint256)" 100000088840000000000667 --rpc-url "$rpc_url" --from "$WALLET_ADDRESS" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY"
        string[] memory inputs = new string[](12);
        inputs[0] = "cast";
        inputs[1] = "send";
        inputs[2] = _tokenAddress;
        inputs[3] = "mint(uint256)";
        inputs[4] = vm.toString(_amount);
        inputs[5] = "--json";
        inputs[6] = "--rpc-url";
        inputs[7] = vm.envString("SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL");
        inputs[8] = "--from";
        inputs[9] = vm.envString("WALLET_ADDRESS");
        inputs[10] = "--private-key";
        inputs[11] = vm.envString("PRIVATE_KEY");

        // Execute the command and get the result
        bytes memory result = vm.ffi(inputs);
        console.log("Cast result",string(result)); //<-- prints JSON above

        if (0 == result.length) {
            console.log("Error: cast call returned empty result");
            revert("Failed to retrieve contract address");
        }

        bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(result); //<--- compilation error
        TransactionReceipt memory transactionReceipt = abi.decode(data, (TransactionReceipt));
        console.log("Transaction Hash: ", transactionReceipt.transactionHash);
        console.log("Transaction Status: ", transactionReceipt.status);
    }
}

Then the compiler complains:
Compiler run failed:
Error (9582): Member "parseJson" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Vm.
  --> test/Functions.sol:59:29:
   |
59 |         bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(result);
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: 
Compilation failed

The path to Vm.sol is correct because a number of previous vm.* calls work.
When I look in Vm.sol, I find:
function parseJson(string calldata json) external pure returns (bytes memory abiEncodedData);

And, my Forge version:
$ forge --version
forge 0.2.0 (be451fb 2024-09-11T00:20:35.367236373Z)


As you've mentioned the parseJson function signature that you found in Vm.sol is:
function parseJson(string calldata json) external pure returns (bytes memory abiEncodedData);

Which shows that it accepts the argument of type string, but the result variable that you're passing is of type bytes. So, you've to typecast that from bytes to string, like:
bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(string(result));

